How to stack 2 query results (Top/Bottom) where the queries may give no results?
How to stack 2 query results (Top/Bottom) where the queries may give no results?
I try to describe my problem clearly.
I am now using the formula "={query(....); query(....)}" to stack two query together. But the queries inside may return no results which make my formula give an Error.
(Update edit my post so that easier to understand)
Given information
Mary    Team A
Paul    Team A
John    Team A
May Team A
Tomy    Team A
Tony    Team A
Peter   Team A
David   Team B
Julia   Team B
INPUT 1
Task 1  May
Task 2  Julia
Task 3  Tony
Task 4  David
Task 5  Paul
Task 6  Tomy
Task 7  Mary
OUTPUT 1 Prefer result (First ordered by Team (A or B) then ordered by the names)
Task 7  Mary
Task 1  May
Task 5  Paul
Task 6  Tomy
Task 3  Tony
Task 4  David
Task 2  Julia
INPUT 2 will blanks and no team B in here
Task 1  May
Task 2  ---
Task 3  Tony
Task 4  ---
Task 5  ---
Task 6  ---
Task 7  ---
Expected output (I am expecting 2 rows as an output, no NA)
Task 1  May
Task 3  Tony
Please edit the following google sheet if you would like to help. Thanks
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1447WljhEwcw2LYZAmoS0v5qlAXRVhWG-eyM3Lb3t-4E/edit?usp=sharing
I tried put a count() on the query results, if the count > 0 (i.e. the query have result >=1 row), then it stacks two query, otherwise, just use one query.
It worked but the formula will be too long and ugly, hard to debug later.

Please post everything needed to answer the question in the question.

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Some one answered me inside the google sheet.
here's the formula
=LET(
  q1_, QUERY(E2:F8,"select * where not F matches 'David|Julia' and not F is null order by F asc",0), 
  q2_, QUERY(E2:F8,"select * where F matches 'David|Julia' and not F is null order by F asc",0),
  x,VSTACK(ifna(q1_,tocol(,1)), ifna(q2_,tocol(,1))),if(iserr(+x),"no data",x))

E2:F8 is the table with two columns , first column is the task, second column is the name of staff (whom was assigned to Team A and B, in my case Julia and David belongs to Team B and I want their data placed at the bottom of the stacked array (if there really are data for them).
Many thanks for the guy helping me out, he just finish it within 1 mins, so cool. Thanks

Code looks like @doubleunary

VSTACK handles empty array spaces better than array joiner literal ;(semicolon).
=LET(
  q1_, QUERY(...), 
  q2_, QUERY(...),
  VSTACK(q1_, q2_)
)


sorry i tried your method on my testing google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1447WljhEwcw2LYZAmoS0v5qlAXRVhWG-eyM3Lb3t-4E/edit?usp=sharing on cell N2, it shows a row with #N/A... That's not my desired result.
